# Using WGET To Download From my.visualstudio.com (MSDN)

Tags: wget, curl, msdn

Ever since MS decided to change over from the old MSDN portal to the new my.visualstudio.com portal I have been having issues with getting the files I need.

Basically the question here is how to use the new portal to get, say, the Windows Server 2016 ISO file, using something like wget or curl.

I am running Cent OS 7 (1611).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just encountered this question after trying to figure it out myself.  I was able to accomplish this by:

1. Using another machine to access my.visualstudio.com from Chrome.
2. Go and find the Windows Server 2016 ISO.
3. Open the developer tools by hitting F12.
4. Go to the network tab.
5. Click on the Download link.
6. Locate the download request from the list of requests that pop up, right click, and choose Copy > Copy as cUrl (bash)

You can then SSH to the machine you want to download it to and paste that command into the prompt.

Remember to add '-o ' or '> ' to actually save the file.

Hope that helps!